# Text repel with a position argument in ggplot/R

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, geom-text, ggrepel

I am trying to make a geom_point where the text labels both repel, and point to their associated points even if I am using position=dodge or position=jitter. I also have a lot of points to label, which is why I want to use ggrepel or something similar. My understanding is that I cannot use the position argument for ggrepel.

Is there any way I can get a plot like this, except with the segments pointing to their associated points?

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggrepel)
data("mtcars")
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)

require(ggplot2)
require(ggrepel)
dodge = position_dodge(1)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = am, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point(size=3, position=dodge, alpha=0.5, aes(color=cyl)) +
  geom_text_repel(data = mtcars,
                  aes(label = mpg, x=am, y=mpg),  alpha=0.9, size=4,
                  segment.size = .25, segment.alpha = .8, force = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Today, I updated ggrepel to support the `position` option in version 0.7.3.

Please try it out and let me know how it goes.

If you have issues, please report them here: https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues

Install version 0.7.3 of ggrepel:

```
devtools::install_github("slowkow/ggrepel")
```

Let's try it:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggrepel)
data("mtcars")
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)

dodge <- position_dodge(1)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = am, y = mpg, label = mpg)) +
  geom_point(
    mapping = aes(color = cyl),
    position = dodge,
    size = 3,
    alpha = 0.5
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    mapping = aes(group = cyl),
    position = dodge,
    size = 4,
    alpha = 0.9,
    segment.size = .25,
    segment.alpha = .8,
    force = 1
  )
```

[image: ggrepel with position]